# how to create a employee multiple Experince in django

Tags: python, django

How to Create Multiple Experinces in Django

This is Model.py Files code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Detail(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class Experince(models.Model):
    detail = models.ForeignKey(Detail, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    date_from = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    date_to = models.CharField(max_length=96)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization
```

This is View.py file code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
#from .forms import *

# Create your views here.



def home(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Detail(first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
        last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
        email_id = request.POST['email_id'],
        mobile_no = request.POST['mobile_no'],
        dob = request.POST['dob'],
        qualification = request.POST['qualification']).save()
        Experince(organization = request.POST['organization'],
        designation = request.POST['designation'],
        date_from = request.POST['date_from'],
        date_to = request.POST['date_to']).save()
    
        
    return render(request,"home.html")
```

This is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
  <title>test page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity=
"sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  
      // Denotes total number of rows
      var rowIdx = 0;
  
      // jQuery button click event to add a row
      $('#addBtn').on('click', function () {
  
        // Adding a row inside the tbody.
        $('#tbody').append(`<tr id="R${++rowIdx}">
             <td class="row-index text-center">
             <p>${rowIdx}</p>
             </td>
            <td class="row-index text-center">
              <input type="text" name="organization">
            </td>
            <td class="row-index text-center">
              <input type="text" name="designation">
            </td>
            <td class="row-index text-center">
              <input type="date" name="date_from">
            </td>
            <td class="row-index text-center">
              <input type="date" name="date_to">
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-danger remove"
                  type="button">Remove</button>
                </td>
              </tr>`);
      });
  
      // jQuery button click event to remove a row.
      $('#tbody').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  
        // Getting all the rows next to the row
        // containing the clicked button
        var child = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll();
  
        // Iterating across all the rows 
        // obtained to change the index
        child.each(function () {
  
          // Getting <tr> id.
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
          // Getting the <p> inside the .row-index class.
          var idx = $(this).children('.row-index').children('p');
  
          // Gets the row number from <tr> id.
          var dig = parseInt(id.substring(1));
  
          // Modifying row index.
          idx.html(`Row ${dig - 1}`);
  
          // Modifying row id.
          $(this).attr('id', `R${dig - 1}`);
        });
  
        // Removing the current row.
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  
        // Decreasing total number of rows by 1.
        rowIdx--;
      });
    });
  </script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row pt-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" name="first_name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 " >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="last name" name="last_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email_id">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" name="mobile_no">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob">
        </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Qualification</h3>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-select" name="qualification">
            <option>Choose...</option>
            <option>B.A</option>
            <option>B.tech.</option>
            <option>BBA</option>
            <option>BCA</option>
            <option>M.tech</option>
            <option>MBA</option>
            <option>MCA</option>
            <option>Other</option>
          </select>
          <div class="pt-3">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S.N</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Organization Name </th>
                  <th class="text-center">Designation</th>
                  <th class="text-center">From </th>
                  <th class="text-center">To</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Remove Row</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tbody">
        
              </tbody>
            </table>
          <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" 
          id="addBtn" type="button">
        Add experince
      </button>
        </div>
            
            
        <div class="col-12 pt-3">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
     
      </div>
      
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a model called Experince with a foreign realation to Detail model. I need to create multiple Experince with experince model. Let's say if the count is 3 then it should save 3 Experince in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are many things gone wrong here. If I understand well, you have users that can have multiple experiences? If that is true, then the user is a master model and experiences is a detail model, and the relation should go the opposite way (experiences have relation to the user model). There are other possibilities, but this is the easiest one.

Than, you are not utilising the django templateing in it's full potential. There is no need to assign all that fields in views, most of this can be accomplished directly.

In the end, if you wish to add on template multiple instances of the detail model (experiences) on the same page, you would probably need to take a look at the formsets that can easily accomplish this.

Hope this helps.